# Может кто-то объяснить почему именно так?

Tags: python, функции

```
def f(x, y):
    global k
    if x > y:
        return False
    if x == y:
        return True
    else:
        return f(x + 1, y) + f(x + 5, y) + f(x * 3, y)


for y in range(2, 100):
    if f(1, y) == 175:
        print(y)
```

[image: Картинка задания]
Почему в данном случае 175 - это количество программ? Это же просто цикл, который подставляет значения к функции? Короче, почему 175 в данном коде - это количество программ?

Comment: вероятно, это простая опечатка

Comment: Это решение выдает правильный ответ.

Comment: Возможно имеется ввиду что вы находите число Х, которое можно получить из единицы 175 способами. То есть количество программ = количество способов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функцию `f` возвращает количество способов получить `y` из `x`. Для этого она рассматривает три случая.

- `x > y`
  Любые три доступных действия увеличивают `x`, поэтому функция возвращает `False` (тоже самое что и ноль)
- `x == y`
  По той же причине это единственный способ, поэтому возвращаем `True` (`1`)
- `x < y`
  Это пара нам не подходит, поэтому рассматриваем три другие (x+1, x+5, 3*x). Они также рассматривают другие случаи пока не дойдут до первых двух условий.

В итоге результат функции, это количество путей до `y`. Затем в цикле поставляются различные `y`, ищя те значение при которых функция вернёт 175.